# Cant access the array object obtained from fetchAll() PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

im learning how use PDO, currently i have a small problem

when use the following lines in my code after prepairing and executing the $tablecount

```
$result = $table_count->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

i get this result as intended

```
[0] => Array ( [TABLE_NAME] => table_1 [0] => table_1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [TABLE_NAME] => table_100 [0] => table_100 )
[2] => Array ( [TABLE_NAME] => table_101 [0] => table_101 )
```

but when i use the below using my theoritical knowledge, it returns an error

```
$result = $table_count->fetchAll();
var_dump($result['TABLE_NAME']);
```

error

```
 Notice: Undefined index: TABLE_NAME
```

can anybody help out of this problem and let know how access what i fetch

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

This will var_dump the table names.

It's because you've got a multidimensional array.